# How can i add full modding support to my Unity game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lua

I've played a bit around with [Unity-Lua](https://github.com/Semaeopus/Unity-Lua) and decidet to add full modding support for my unity game. But it dosn't really work that well... Unity-Lua has some major things missing that i need to add full modding support.
**Is there a good and easy to understand alternative?**

I want the player to fully mod the game, and be able to change everything like ui, items, enemies.
The concept of the game is just, there is nothing in the actual but you can change that with mods to make whatever game you want.

Thanks :)

Comment: To my knowledge, apart from open-sourcing the game (which is often complex in other ways, e.g. legally if you're using elements under different licenses), there's no easy way to do this. I hope I'm wrong and there's something I don't know about though.

Comment: but how dose minecraft forge/fabric handle this? these mods are also licensed or are they?

Comment: They manage their mod support by having no relation to Unity. If you mean about open-source licensing: if you make a game using assets from the Unity asset store for example, in most cases you won’t be allowed to open-source those assets meaning you can’t open-source your whole game without replacing them.

Comment: yeah, but i wont use all that stuff, i only use moonsharp library

Comment: If you own all the assets or have appropriate licenses you can open-source your project if you want. (Moonsharp allows source redistribution as long as you don't remove their [license](https://github.com/moonsharp-devs/moonsharp/blob/master/LICENSE) so that should be fine.) That would allow anyone to modify and redistribute the source files or binaries under whatever license terms you choose.